# Issue with file manager in swift 3.1

Tags: swift, xcode8, ios10, swift3

I have the below code that worked fine, up until the release of swift 3.1.

```
func loadImage() {

    id = userPhotoModel.id

    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    let imagePath = (self.getDirectoryPath() as NSString).appendingPathComponent(photoName)

    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagePath){
        let imageFromPath = resizeImage(named: (contentsOfFile: imagePath))

        print("name of photo retrieved: \(photoName)")

        self.userPhoto.image = imageFromPath

    }else{
        print("No Image")
    }
}
```

Now, swift 3.1 wants to add as! String to:

```
let imageFromPath = resizeImage(named: (contentsOfFile: imagePath) as! String)
```

However, when I run the app, it crashes in this location with no error message as per the below image.

What is causing this?

[image]

EDIT: Here is the resizeImage func

```
fileprivate func resizeImage(named name: String) -> UIImage
{

    var image = UIImage(named: name)

    if image!.size.height > image!.size.width
    {
        self.userPhoto.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    }
    else
    {
        image = image!.resizeTo(self.userPhoto.bounds)
    }
    return image!
}
```

Comment: What is `resizeImage` and its declaration? What is the expression `(contentsOfFile: imagePath)` supposed to be?

Comment: I am allowing user to add their own image.  This is where I take the existing name and add "_full".jpg to each image (to match current image already loaded).  This file name get appended to the imagePath.

Comment: But what is the `contentsOfFile:` part of that expression? Why isn't the line simply: `let imageFromPath = resizeImage(named: imagePath)` ?

Comment: Honestly, don't recall why I added that extra step, but your suggestion worked and fixed it.  Put it as the answer and I will accept it.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the confusing syntax in the line:

```
let imageFromPath = resizeImage(named: (contentsOfFile: imagePath))
```

That should simply be:

```
let imageFromPath = resizeImage(named: imagePath)
```

No cast required and correct in any Swift 3.x.